# hardhat-chai-matchers: How to distinguish if a transaction was reverted because it ran out of gas or other reason?

Tags: hardhat, testing, out-of-gas, chai

I'm trying to force a ran out of gas error and test it using the new Hardhat's assertion library, @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers.

First I tried a very low gas of 1:

```
await expect(_attack.attack({ gasLimit: 1 }))
.to.be.revertedWith("TransactionExecutionError: Transaction ran out of gas");
```

I've received a message error `InvalidInputError: Transaction requires at least 21064 gas but got 1`.

Then I tried just change the revert message as the following code and there is no change in the result:

```
await expect(_attack.attack({ gasLimit: 1 }))
.to.be.revertedWith("TransactionExecutionError: Transaction ran out of gas");
```

Next, I tried to change the gasLimit to the least value cited in the InvalidInputError:

```
await expect(_attack.attack({ gasLimit: 21064 }))
.to.be.revertedWith("TransactionExecutionError: Transaction ran out of gas");
```

Then I've received the following assertion error message: `AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with reason 'TransactionExecutionError: Transaction ran out of gas', but it reverted without a reason`.

What makes me do this question: It is not possible to distinguish a transaction reverted for running out of gas?

I've picked the following snippet from Hardhat docs where they tell about revertedWithoutReason: `you can assert that a call reverted without any error data (neither a reason string, nor a panic code, nor a custom error)`.

When a transaction has no gas we really don't have something that identifies the cause? Or this is just the case of Hardhat Node?

The code of contracts being tested are in here: https://github.com/fabianorodrigo/ethereum-experiments/tree/main/contracts/learnweb3/randomness

And the test here: https://github.com/fabianorodrigo/ethereum-experiments/blob/main/test/learnweb3/randomness.ts

Thank you very much,